# Best way to pass object to function inside a loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

Inside a while loop I create a string object on each iteration. Then I create a new object. The constructor of the object is passed the string by value as one of the parameters(so each new object has its own copy of the string).
There are several threads picking up the objects from the queue as the queue is filled  for processing them, each thread gets an object from the queue, does whatever it needs to do with it.

Something like this:

```
unsigned char Raw_Request_Bytes[2048] = {'\0'};

while(1) {
    std::string sTemp ((char *)Raw_Request_Bytes);
    MyObject * pObj = new MyObject(sTemp);
    MyQueue.Add(pObj);
    memset(Raw_Request_Bytes,0,sizeof(Raw_Request_Bytes));  
}
```

I do it that way because while testing/designing I noticed that each time that I create the string its address is the same, and I thought that then each object wont have its own copy of the string but the same one IF I passed a pointer to the string.

am I right? is there a better way to do it? I am kind of concerned with the impact of creating a copy of the string each time (aprox. 2048 chars)

Comment: What populates `Raw_Request_Bytes`?

Comment: It depends on what `MyObject` does with its constructor argument. It *should* copy the string, in which case everything should be fine. If it instead stores a reference or pointer to the string, then it's a deathtrap.

Comment: so basicly you want to copy the string and let each object have it's own copy of the same string? if so your object should use something like this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/ to handle the string, to make sure the object just takes a copy, the object should do this itself, so that it not depends what is passed to the object and it makes sure to have it's own copy

Comment: trojanfoe -> a sockets is reading and putting the read info into Raw_Request_Bytes

Comment: Mike-> yes, the constructor copies the string, so there is no prob right now, my question is b/c I would like to know if there is a better way to do it, since copying big strings takes some time

Comment: Instead of asking, wouldn't it have been easier to just loop over the objects afterwards printing out the strings they have, and see for yourself if they are different?

Comment: soulan -> isn't that the same as assigning the argument in the constructor to a member variable?

Comment: andy -> Your remark is not necessary, I was asking to hopefully get an answer that would help me or others. I wasn't asking "what would happen" but if there is a better way, a perfect valid question. If you are bothered with people asking for help or guide (which is what this place is for) then simply don't participate.

Answer (score 0):

> I do it that way because while testing/designing I noticed that each
>   time that I create the string its address is the same, and I thought
>   that then each object wont have its own copy of the string but the
>   same one IF I passed a pointer to the string.

You see std::string created on the stack, so it is not a surprise that in a loop it's memory address is the same on every iteration. But your object will have it's own copy of the string, unless `MyObject` holds a reference to it, which is UB anyway. You probably confusing `std::string` with raw C string - `char *`, but that the whole point why `std::string` added to the language - it behaves like normal object, not like pointer.

if you look into this code:

```
 void foo( int param );

 while( 1 ) {
     int i = 123;
     ... // do something with i
     foo( i );
 }
```

`i` address is most probably the same on every iteration. Don't you worry that foo will get a copy or not? Same story with `std::string`

> is there a better way to do it? I am kind of concerned with the impact
>   of creating a copy of the string each time (aprox. 2048 chars)

First of all it is not mandatory that you copy 2048 chars every time. In the form you wrote `std::string` initializing, it will copy part of string till \0. About your concern, if you need to keep that strings somewhere, there is no other choice than to allocate memory for them. Is there better way? It is difficult to say without seeing whole picture. If you need to store tens of that strings on normal desktop PC, it does not really matter. Better way is to write readable and bug free code. Do micro optimizations only when necessary.